# Twitter Bootstrap customization and download

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the Twitter Bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. I selected the required components and then clicked on the "compile and download" button. It seems that this button is disabled and I was not able to download.

Can you please help me in customizing and downloading twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google chrome browser.

The first time you click compile and download, the button is disabled and the download starts in the background.

i could do it flawlessly.

If it fails this time. press ctrl+shift+R

Answer (score 0):

**There is a warning before download:**
*Warning for Firefox users!
Due to a possible browser bug, the customizer download randomly fails in Firefox. If this happens to you, we advise either retrying in Firefox or using one of the other browsers supported by the Customizer (Chrome or IE10+).*

Please use a compliant browser and it should work. In case it does not please provide your customization details.

Comment: I tried in chrome browser. I selected only, all the common css options, input groups, navs, navbar,jumbotron from components.

Comment: I am getting the below succes message with download. 'Success! Your configuration has been saved to https://gist.github.com/b6726e8cd4124cd9093f and can be revisited here at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=b6726e8cd4124cd9093f for further customization.' Check the links to see if any other customizations are there.

Comment: Thanks sashwat. Now I am able to download the custom files.